# How to make MATLAB script wait for an external event to occur?

Tags: matlab, events, async-await, event-handling, wait

I have a MATLAB script that connects to an external machine and starts an operation like so:

```
% Connecting and initialising...
machine.Go()

% wait function until 'End' event

% Rest of script...
```

The machine should raise an event at the end of the operation. After the operation ends with an event `End` I want to execute the rest of my script.

The documentation (from the machine) says that an event handler should be of the form:

```
void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
```

which seems quite generic. I'm not familiar with events and handlers.

What is the best way to make MATLAB wait until this `End` event occurs?

I have seen a couple of solutions with timers, but I don't want to use these as the operations are of varying lengths. I also don't want to use a while loop as this seems inefficient.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Managed it with this:

```
t = timer('TimerFcn',@(~,~)disp('This is the timer callback function.'),'StartDelay',100000);
start(t);

% Create a listener for CollectionEnd event that will interrupt this timer
addlistener(fc,'End',@(~,~)stop(t));

% Wait until timer stopped
wait(t);
```